# docker add "requires at least one argument" error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a folder which contains all the necessary components for an app, which I want to make a container of. I have everything set up so far, with the directory  `/home/user/Documents/App` in the Dockerfile under the ADD heading. Then when I`docker build .` in the App directory I get this

> ADD /home/user/Documents/App
>   ADD requires at least one argument

I realize that this is probably a simple fix but I am new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
FROM alpine
ADD </home/user/Documents/App> </home/user/Documents/DockerApp>
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPPOSE 8080
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Please include your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

You need a source and destination for the ADD command. The source here is the app folder path. The destination should be where you want the dockerfile is run.

Try this I think it might work

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried using a source and destination like this in the Dockerfile   "ADD </home/userDocuments/App>  </home/user/Documents/DockerApp> "   but Terminal told me there is no such directory? Or how is it supposed to be written?

Comment: Did that, it still says no such file or directory for the App folder >:(

Comment: I'm sorry the DEST should be the directory location in the container. You are copying contents of /Documents/App to /somewhere/in/container

Comment: Ignore that last comment, sorry. So I now have "ADD  /home/user/Documents/App" and below that " DEST /home/user/Documents/DockerApp"  ...... But I am  being told it requires at least one argument?

Comment: It should be something like this.....    ADD /home/user/Documents/App /home/user/

Comment: the container will most probably not have a /Documents/DockerApp folder..... throw into something that already exists

Answer (score 0):

ADD defined in Dockerfile has the following structure

```
ADD sourceJarName destinationJarName
```

e.g.

```
ADD target/spring-boot-rest-docker-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
```

change your ADD likewise and try it will work